# Why I can't set vertical-align middle for img tag

Tags: html, css

Hello I am very new to HTML and CSS and I am trying to do a site for just learning. I just made a header and I put logo in it but I can't set it's vertical-align. Can someone explain it?

Here is HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Scienitive</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo-container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href ="index.html"><img src ="logo.png"></a>
            </div>
            <h1>Scienitive</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is CSS file:

```
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
display: block;
background-color: #FF5733;
}
.logo-container {
height: 100%;
display: table;
float: left;
}
.logo-container h1{
color: white;
height: 100%;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
font-family: "Open Sans";
font-size: 48px;

}
.logo {
display: table;
height: 80px;
}
.logo img{
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
}
```

Here is how site looks like
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPAxJ.png)

Comment: your img stand aside nothing to vertical iself : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align , you should make logo `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't want to set the `display: table-cell` or `vertical-align: middle` on the `img` tag directly, but instead on its container/parent:

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FF5733;
}

.logo-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.logo-container h1 {
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 48px;
}

.logo {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 80px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Scienitive</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="//placehold.it/48x48"></a>
      </div>
      <h1>Scienitive</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

vertical-align is to be set on the table-cell container , which .logo should be

reminder to read about vertical-align : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

```css
  .header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FF5733;
}

.logo-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.logo-container h1 { 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 48px;
}

.logo {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;;
  height: 80px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <h1>Scienitive</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If the area to click should only be the image, then you can consider using flex to center content or reduce the click area via pointer-events . Plese clarify if so